# Using DNS to access ASP.NET with Windows Auth

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, dns

Wondering if you can help me here, been battering away at this for days now.

i have an IIS site with windows authentication installed, which is working exactly the way it should do.  This particular IIS Server houses approx 6 other sites so i have create a new Site called Helpdeskv6, with Application Pool Helpdeskv6 set to .NET 4 integrated using ApplicationPoolIndentity.  We are currently working on a 2008 R2 domain, no windows firewall etc.

So i have now created a A Record that gives it a nice little name for our intranet users, the A record is called helpdesk (FQDN: helpdesk.my.domain).  The IIS site is setup with bindings on standard port 80 for both helpdesk and the FQDN.  but yet when i try and browse to the A record address it constantly prompts me for username and password.  When i enter my details they work but i dont want users to be prompted.

i have ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentiation enabled - Providers are NTLM and Negotiate.  ASP Impersonation is Auth User. NTLM Authentication is ticked in my ASP Project Web Property page.

i have tried just enabling and disabling so many different settings, i have used setsnp -S HTTP/helpdesk.my.domain webserver001 and i have used setsmp -S HTTP/helpdesk webserver001 as i have read alot that apparently needs these in but nothing seems to work.

i have never used ASP Auth with a A Record before so i am at a severe loss please help, hope i supplied enough information as i do not want to have users entere their windows authentication constantly it should be auto so i am just fearfull i am missing a trick here as when i browse via netbios name it works but this is not appropriate for our environment

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to close this out,

The issue was becuase the site wasnt being registered as a Intranet site and Auth details where not being transported over.